Не понимаю где в коде бота ошибка
(имеется ввиду не строка в которой ошибка, а причина этой ошибки и способы ее исправления)
писал код, и наткнулся на ошибку с этой строкой:
const discordBot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\rdnews bot\rdnews.js:9:51)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

собственно вот весь код, смысл которого перекидывать сообщения из тг канала в дискорд:
сonst TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// настройки для телеграмм бота
const telegramToken = '';
const telegramChannelUsername = '';

// настройки для дискорд бота
const discordToken = '';
const discordChannelId = '';
const { Intents } = require('discord.js');

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        // ...
    ]
})

// создаем бота телеграм
const telegramBot = new TelegramBot(telegramToken, { polling: true });

// создаем клиента дискорд
const discordClient = new Discord.Client();
discordClient.login(discordToken);

// отправляем сообщение в дискорд
function sendToDiscord(message) {
    const channel = discordClient.channels.cache.get(discordChannelId);
    if (channel) {
        channel.send(message);
    } else {
        console.log("Дискорд канал не найден.");
    }
}

// слушаем сообщения в телеграм канале
telegramBot.on('message', (msg) => {
   if (msg.chat && msg.chat.username === telegramChannelUsername.replace('@', '')) {
   const message = msg.text || "Неподдерживаемый тип сообщения";
   sendToDiscord(message);
   }
});

// обрабатываем ошибки
telegramBot.on('polling_error', console.log);
discordClient.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Дискорд бот ${discordClient.user.tag} готов!`);
});
client.login(TOKEN)


какую версию discord.js вы используете?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14/73028855#73028855

@nörbörnën прошу прощения, но как это узнать, програмист из меня некудышный

@nörbörnën +-- https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js?sponsor
|   `-- discord.js@14.15.3, @discordjs/builders@1.8.2, @discordjs/formatters@0.4.0, @discordjs/rest@2.3.0, @discordjs/collection@2.1.0, @discordjs/util@1.1.0, @discordjs/ws@1.1.1
может вы имелли ввиду это?

переписал код к чертям, ошибка изменилась: теперь это: "TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client."

в вашем коде дважды создаётся Discord Client

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Ошибка при запуске бота на JS
